# docker-ce not showing up in `yum list available` with repo installed

Tags: docker, centos7, yum

Edit: I'd still like an answer to this question if possible, but I have managed to work around it by directly installing the individual rpms rather than relying on yum to do it for me.

I'm struggling with installing docker-ce on a CentOS 7 box.  I have it installed on three other boxes, but the fourth is giving me problems.  I am following the instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/).  Installing the repo appears to work, but `docker-ce` doesn't appear to be available no matter what I try.

```
$ sudo yum-config-manager \
>     --add-repo \
>     https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
adding repo from: https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
grabbing file https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo to /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo
repo saved to /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo

$ ls /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo

# This should include docker-ce, docker-ce-cli, and a few other things
$ yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="docker-ce-stable" list available
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Available Packages
containerd.io.x86_64                                 1.2.6-3.3.el7                                  docker-ce-stable

$ sudo yum install docker-ce
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.fileplanet.com
 * epel: mirror.colorado.edu
 * extras: mirrors.tummy.com
 * updates: mirrors.tummy.com
No package docker-ce available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

The repo is obviously enabled.  I am able to install `containerd.io` from the repo.  It just appears that nothing else is available in the repo.  Even when I copy the repo from another CentOS7 box where it works, I still don't see the docker-ce package.  This repo worked fine on three other boxes tonight.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

## Edit:

Running `yum clean all` and  `yum update` have not helped.

```
$ rm /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo
rm: remove regular file ‘/etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo’? y

$ yum clean all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Cleaning repos: base epel extras updates
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
Other repos take up 18 M of disk space (use --verbose for details)

$ yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                         |  14 kB  00:00:00
 * base: repos.forethought.net
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
 * extras: repos.forethought.net
 * updates: repos.forethought.net
base                                                                                         | 3.6 kB  00:00:00
epel                                                                                         | 5.4 kB  00:00:00
extras                                                                                       | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
updates                                                                                      | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
(1/7): base/7/x86_64/group_gz                                                                | 165 kB  00:00:00
(2/7): base/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                              | 6.0 MB  00:00:00
(3/7): epel/x86_64/group_gz                                                                  |  90 kB  00:00:00
(4/7): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                | 1.0 MB  00:00:00
(5/7): extras/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                            | 153 kB  00:00:00
(6/7): updates/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                           | 2.8 MB  00:00:00
(7/7): epel/x86_64/primary_db                                                                | 6.9 MB  00:00:01
No packages marked for update

$ yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
adding repo from: https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
grabbing file https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo to /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo
repo saved to /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo

$ yum list available | grep docker-ce
containerd.io.x86_64                      1.2.10-3.2.el7                 docker-ce-stable

$ yum install docker-ce
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repos.forethought.net
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
 * extras: repos.forethought.net
 * updates: repos.forethought.net
No package docker-ce available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

```
$ yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="docker-ce-stable" list available
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Available Packages
containerd.io.x86_64                                 1.2.10-3.2.el7                                 docker-ce-stable
```

Comment: try `yum clean all`then install it

Comment: Unfortunately, no, that didn't do it.  I still only see containerd.io in the repo and nothing else.  Thanks, though!

Comment: Try `yum update` before install command

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either.  I ran `yum update`, then `yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo` which worked as expected, `yum install docker-ce` still returns "No package docker-ce available" and `yum list available | grep docker-ce` still only shows `container.io`.

Comment: I just tried running all the commands you gave and it worked fine for me on a new CentOS 7.5 vm. I think you can not run `yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="docker-ce-stable" list available` and it will also work.

Comment: Yeah, this is just weird...  I think I just need to reinstall the OS at this point to get this to work.

```
$ yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="docker-ce-stable" list available
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Available Packages
containerd.io.x86_64                                 1.2.10-3.2.el7                                 docker-ce-stable
```

Comment: Also, see the edit at the end of the question.

Comment: Can you try `yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="docker-ce-stable" --disableexcludes=all list available`?

Comment: That is working, actually.  Yesterday it didn't, but I have gone through an purged a lot of stuff since then.  Maybe getting closer.

Comment: @EduardoBaitello Apparently someone had added `exclude=docker*` to `/etc/yum.conf`.  Problem solved!  Since your comment lead me to the answer, if you submit an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad to help. I added an answer for future people facing the same problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways of enforcing yum to exclude a repo. One of them is by setting the `exclude` directive on `/etc/yum.conf`. This config has priority over the `--disablerepo` and `--enablerepo` flags.

You must check your `/etc/yum.conf`, removing the exclude **or** forcing yum to ignore it using the `--disableexcludes=all` flag.

> ```
> --disableexcludes=[all|main|repoid]
> Disable  the excludes defined in your config files. Takes one of three options:
>
> all == disable all excludes
> main == disable excludes defined in [main] in yum.conf
> repoid == disable excludes defined for that repo
> ```

e.g:

`yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="docker-ce-stable" --disableexcludes=all list available`

Comment: Apparently I can't award the bounty yet.  It says I need to wait 7 hours.  I'll award it then.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

- Create a directory `/etc/yum.repos.d/disabled` and move everything from `/etc/yum.repos.d` to this new directory
- Run `yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo`. Now you should see a `docker-ce.repo` file under `/etc/yum.repos.d`.
- Run `yum clean all && yum list available` and then check if you see
  `docker-ce.x86_64` among the available packages

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Although it makes no sense, I get the same result as before.  I think I just need to start from scratch on this box.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `yum repolist -v docker-ce-stable`?

Answer (score 0):

Execute the command below and try it.

yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2

yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.rep

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try installing it without slash ''

wrong - sudo yum-config-manager \ --add-repo \ https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

right - sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo